# Truncate arbitrary File Geodatabase tables in FME

Tags: esri-geodatabase, fme-form

I have one FGDB with over 30 tables. Also have few WB and they write data to output tables in FGDB, but each of WB write data to different tables but still at the same FGDB. Output tables are being truncated first (set option Parameters). But I also need the rest of tables in this database to be truncated every time WB is started, no matter which one.
Because the problem is that FGDB is going to be updated only with data accoridng to spesific WB, but there are still data in other tables not used by WB.
I hope someone understand my issue.
Tnx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's okay to truncate all the data in the geodatabase, is it also okay to delete and recreate the geodatabase every time one of these workspaces runs? If so, this sounds like a really good case for using a Geodatabase template file (ESRI XML Workspace document) in FME 2012.

See this [FME Evangelist article](http://evangelism.safe.com/fmeevangelist95/) for an introduction and the ESRI Geodatabase Writer documentation on the [TEMPLATEFILE](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_ReadersWriters/geodatabase/writer/templatefile.htm) directive for more details.

Just be sure to set the Overwrite Geodatabase parameter to true, but note that file locking by other programs like the FME Universal Viewer and ArcCatalog will prevent the geodatabase from being deleted.

If you can't delete the geodatabase every time, then I would suggest writing a Python startup script to truncate the tables using FME Objects, arcpy, or the file geodatabase API.

Another possibility would be creating a workspace expressly for truncating all the tables, and then calling that workspace using a WorkspaceRunner transformer.